# Parsing irregular JSON fields in Python

Tags: python, json

Consider this json format:

```
{
"HostSystem(\"host-527\")": {},
"HostSystem(\"host-487\")": {},
"HostSystem(\"host-482\")": {
    "hardware.cpuInfo.numCpuThreads": 2,
    "name": "192.168.1.1",
    "config.network.consoleVnic": [],
    "capability.perVmSwapFiles": true,
    "capability.maxRunningVMs": 0,
    "config.dateTimeInfo.timeZone.name": "UTC",
}
```

I'd like to parse out 'name'  and 'hardware.cpuInfo.numCpuThreads' from each 'HostSystem' but I'm failing to read the key properly and it doesn't appear that I can use a wildcard.

This is my starter code to test out reading 'HostSystem *' and its failing miserably.

```
import json

with open("blob.json") as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)
    print data['HostSystem *']
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: In addition, I'd like to display the information for each iteration of 
    "HostSystem(\"host-*\"). Example output I'd like to see is: "HostSystem(\"host-482\") - hardware.cpuInfo.numCpuThreads 2,  name - 192.168.1.1

Answer (score 2):

Here it is:

```
import json

with open("blob.json") as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)

for k in data:
    if 'hardware.cpuInfo.numCpuThreads' in data[k]:
        print data[k]['hardware.cpuInfo.numCpuThreads']
```

Comment: I think this answer could be improved by using list /dict comprehension to output a list or dictionary, rather than printing.

Comment: Thank you for your updates. I've added additional comments to my request although this is on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Is your json data copied properly? If so, you're failing parsing json data because it's not valid format.

Check whether your json format is in a correct format in Online Json Editor (http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/). Your should delete comma at the end of `"config.dateTimeInfo.timeZone.name": "UTC",` and add `}` after it.